# Putting top-level launch files in a catkin metapackage

Tags: ros, roslaunch, catkin, ros-hydro, metapackage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a metapackage that is set up as specified on the `package.xml` ROS wiki page (I don't have enough karma to publish the link). I would like to use this metapackage to hold the top-level launch files I will use for this particular collection of packages. I have added a `launch/` directory to my metapackage's top-level directory and created a launch file in that directory, but when I try to run it with roslaunch (`roslaunch <package_name> <launch_file>`), I get the following error:

```
[<launch_file>] is neither a launch file in package [<package_name>] nor is [<package_name>] a launch file name
```

I have two questions regarding this:

1. Is it good practice---or even supported---to put top-level launch files in a metapackage? Or do I need to place the launch files in their own package? The advantage that I see to putting them in the metapackage is that I would only have to maintain a list of dependencies in one `package.xml` file, as opposed to two if I had both a metapackage and a launch file package. But is there a reason why this would be a bad idea?
2. If it is good practice to keep the launch files in the metapackage, what can I do to fix the roslaunch error? I thought maybe I might need to add a line to my `CMakeLists.txt` file, but the wiki page mentioned above recommends not deviating from the boilerplate `CMakeLists.txt` code. So would this even be supported? (If it's not supported does anybody know the reasoning behind that decision?)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/91246/putting-top-level-launch-files-in-a-catkin-metapackage/) by [dpkoch](https://answers.ros.org/users/7781/dpkoch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 132 on 2013-10-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. A metapackage may not install any files, except its `package.xml`, which is done automatically.
2. No, don't use a metapackage, convert it to an ordinary catkin package. Then, you can [add the necessary install() commands](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/installing_other.html) to your `CMakeLists.txt`. An ordinary package with the same dependencies will serve much the same purpose as your metapackage did.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2